# How to deploy multiple pods with same a helm chart?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I want to deploy multiple ML models in different pods within the same namespace. But whenever I pull a new image from aws ECR and deploy it using helm it terminates the current running pod and makes a new one. So I am unable to deploy multiple models. Every time it kills the previous one and makes a new pod.

```
helm upgrade --install tf-serving ./charts/tf-serving/ --namespace mlhub
```

OR

```
helm upgrade --recreate-pods --install tf-serving ./charts/tf-serving/ --namespace mlhub
```

> ```
> tf-serving-8559fb87d-2twwl        1/1     Running       0          37s  
> tf-serving-8559fb87d-m6hgs        0/1     Terminating   0          45s
> ```

It kills the previous one and makes a new, but the images of both models are different with different tags also.

Comment: Can you run `helm install` multiple times with different release names and values files?

Comment: So do i have to create new charts for every model and deploy it with the same namespace?  I am a newbie to kubernetes, please help!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can use one Helm chart to create multiple Releases. For example to deploy first model:

```
helm install ./charts/tf-serving/ --name tf-serving --namespace mlhub
```

And if you later want to add another one:

```
helm install ./charts/tf-serving/ --name tf-serving2 --namespace mlhub
```

Now when you run `helm list` you will be able to see both `tf-serving` and `tf-serving2`.

Be aware that you can not have multiple Kubernetes resources of the same Kind with the same name, so I would recommend using `{{ .Release.Name }}` value in your chart, as a prefix for all deployed resources.

**EDIT**:

Since Helm v3, `--name` flag does not exist anymore. Instead, you can run: `helm install  tf-serving ./charts/tf-serving/ --namespace mlhub`.

Credit to [Pieber](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7831181/pieber)

Comment: THANKS @Szymig 
This worked for me ... 

''' helm upgrade --recreate-pods --install <NAME> ./charts/tf-serving/ -f envs/$environment/tf-serving-values.yaml --namespace mlhub '''

This also worked in similar way.

Comment: Since Helm v3, `--name` flag does not exist anymore. Instead, you can run: `helm install  tf-serving ./charts/tf-serving/ --namespace mlhub`.